# Avoid sql injection ActiveRecord order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection

I am trying to avoid sql injection when ordering but I also need to make sure NULLS are last.

```
query = books.order(@vals['order'] + ' NULLS LAST')
```

But if I take @vals['order'] as an API parameter I am susceptible to sql injection.  Is there a better way to form the order to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really only an API, I would only offer certain kinds of ordering to your API consumers and catch the order criteria upfront in your code (e.g. a whitelisting approach).

```
if @evals['order'] == 'title'
  ordering = 'title'
elsif @evals['order'] == 'published'
  ordering = 'created_at'
else
  ordering = 'id'
end

query = books.order(ordering + ' NULLS LAST')
```

It's not the prettiest of codes, but at least you will be safe without the need to parse the parameter.

Comment: Not as ugly as dealing with injection after the fact ;)  Thanks!

Comment: Any way to dynamically allow order on any column in the table.  I.E. without hardcoding all columns.

Comment: Puh... I don't know from the top of my head, but maybe you can look into the AR documentation to see if there is a function which gives you all the attributes for the model. Then you can iterate through that... but really, I don't know from the top of my head.

Comment: awesome, no worries I can look.  Will post if I find it.  Thanks.